# In FXRuby when trying to specify a font I get an error "FXDCWindow::setFont: illegal or NULL font specified.", how to fix this?

Tags: ruby, fonts, fxruby

In Ruby when trying to specify a font I get an error "FXDCWindow::setFont: illegal or NULL font specified.". I tried doing it like this:

```
@font = FXFont.new(app, 'times')
```

I need to set a font in order to use drawText in my program and I can't figure out how to. Oh and for the record I'm justt a beginner. Thanks!

Comment: "app" is the application instance (app = FXApp.new0 , I think "Self" works just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.fxruby.org/doc/api/), you need to specify the size at least. Try:

```
@font = FXFont.new(app, "times,12")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not trying to use the font object before it has been created; see http://www.fox-toolkit.org/faq.html#ILLEGALICON.